# Whenever velocity is 0, add up the amount of time it stays zero (r)

Tags: r

This is my first time here. I've managed to get through most of this code myself, but am stuck on this last part.

I've created the tibble below after reading data from a device. It calculates velocity based off time and distance collected from the device, calculates a rolling average, then cleans it by setting anything under a threshold to 0

I'm trying to sum up the duration that cleaned velocity is 0. This way I can subtract it from the final time to get the amount of time the wheel was rolling.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
    time distance slope `rolling velocity avg` `clean velocity`
   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>                  <dbl>            <dbl>
 1  2.51     0    0                     0.164             0    
 2  3.55     0    0.168                 0.327             0.327
 3  4.56     0.17 0.486                 0.450             0.450
 4  5.61     0.68 0.654                 0.567             0.567
 5  6.65     1.36 0.490                 0.527             0.527
 6  7.69     1.87 0.638                 0.364             0.364
 7  8.74     2.54 0.327                 0.241             0.241
 8  9.78     2.88 0                     0.0817            0    
 9 10.8      2.88 0                     0                 0    
10 11.9      2.88 0                     0.0810            0    
11 12.9      2.88 0                     0.285             0.285
12 14.0      2.88 0.324                 0.449             0.449
13 15        3.22 0.817                 0.651             0.651
14 16.0      4.07 0.654                 0.731             0.731
15 17.1      4.75 0.810                 0.649             0.649
```

Edit:
I would add a 6th column titled "period stopped." This column would have the elapsed time from the start of a zeros until it became a non-zero value. It would make sense to put it at the end of the stopped period. For example, rows 8 to 10 have no velocity, so it would subtract [10,1] - [8,1] and output that elapsed time at [10,6]. Any time a new sequence of zeros comes up, it would do the same until it reaches the end of the tibble

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To be able to help you out, could you please provide how you expect your result to look like?

Comment: Hi Wietse, thanks for the welcome!
I would add a 6th column titled "period stopped."
This column would have the elapsed time from the start of a zeros until it became a non-zero value. It would make sense to put it at the end of the stopped period. For example, rows 8 to 10 have no velocity, so it would subtract [10,1] - [8,1] and output that elapsed time at [10,6]. Any time a new sequence of zeros comes up, it would do the same until it reaches the end of the tibble

Comment: Comments should not be used to clarify questions.  the question should stand on their own.  Edit the question to clarify it and then add a comment explaining what change was made or where to look in the question to see the clarification.   Also the question should show the expected answer exactly as it would be produced from R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what I can suggest.

Step 1: Create a new column, calculated as time difference between each consecutive row (assuming they are sorted correctly):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(t_lead = lead(time)-time)

    time distance slope rolling_velocity_avg clean_velocity t_lead
1   2.51     0.00 0.000               0.1640          0.000   1.04
2   3.55     0.00 0.168               0.3270          0.327   1.01
3   4.56     0.17 0.486               0.4500          0.450   1.05
4   5.61     0.68 0.654               0.5670          0.567   1.04
5   6.65     1.36 0.490               0.5270          0.527   1.04
6   7.69     1.87 0.638               0.3640          0.364   1.05
7   8.74     2.54 0.327               0.2410          0.241   1.04
8   9.78     2.88 0.000               0.0817          0.000   1.02
9  10.80     2.88 0.000               0.0000          0.000   1.10
10 11.90     2.88 0.000               0.0810          0.000   1.00
11 12.90     2.88 0.000               0.2850          0.285   1.10
12 14.00     2.88 0.324               0.4490          0.449   1.00
13 15.00     3.22 0.817               0.6510          0.651   1.00
14 16.00     4.07 0.654               0.7310          0.731   1.10
15 17.10     4.75 0.810               0.6490          0.649     NA
```

Step 2: Filter `clean_velocity == 0` and sum up `t_lead`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(t_lead = lead(time)-time) %>%
  filter(clean_velocity == 0) %>%
  summarize(sum_time = sum(t_lead))

  sum_time
1     4.16
```

Comment: The first part of the code works
`
cleanwheeltibble %>%
  mutate(t_lead = lead(time)-time)
`
But when I do the whole thing this is the output 
`# A tibble: 1 x 1
  sum_time
     <dbl>
1       NA
`

Comment: Add `na.rm=T` inside the sum function? Another option is to add  `%>%na.omit()%>%` before `summarizie`

Comment: This seems wrong. It does not return a 6 column data frame in which position 10,6 is 2.12 which is what was asked for in a comment below the question.

Comment: What I did was put the first two lines `df %>%
  mutate(t_lead = lead(time)-time)` into a new dataframe

into `df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(t_lead = lead(time)-time)`

that outputs a new table with 6 columns

Answer (score 1):

Assume the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.

In a comment the poster of the question stated that the last element of a new column for each consecutive group of zeros should be the difference between the first and last time, i.e. the difference between the maximum and minimum time in that group.  The other values were not defined but we assume that any undefined component should be 0.  `rleid` from data.table is used to give each group of consecutive elements a unique id (alternately use `groupid` from the collapse package) and we multiply by `clean_velocity==0` to zero out any element that does not correspond to a 0.

```
library(data.table) # rleid

DF[10,1] - DF[8,1] # check: expected value in position 10,6 of result
## [1] 2.12

FUN <- function(x) c(rep(0, length(x)-1), diff(range(x)))
transform(DF, stopped = 
  (clean_velocity == 0) * (ave(time, rleid(clean_velocity), FUN = FUN)))

    time distance slope rolling_velocity_avg clean_velocity stopped
1   2.51     0.00 0.000               0.1640          0.000    0.00
2   3.55     0.00 0.168               0.3270          0.327    0.00
3   4.56     0.17 0.486               0.4500          0.450    0.00
4   5.61     0.68 0.654               0.5670          0.567    0.00
5   6.65     1.36 0.490               0.5270          0.527    0.00
6   7.69     1.87 0.638               0.3640          0.364    0.00
7   8.74     2.54 0.327               0.2410          0.241    0.00
8   9.78     2.88 0.000               0.0817          0.000    0.00
9  10.80     2.88 0.000               0.0000          0.000    0.00
10 11.90     2.88 0.000               0.0810          0.000    2.12
11 12.90     2.88 0.000               0.2850          0.285    0.00
12 14.00     2.88 0.324               0.4490          0.449    0.00
13 15.00     3.22 0.817               0.6510          0.651    0.00
14 16.00     4.07 0.654               0.7310          0.731    0.00
15 17.10     4.75 0.810               0.6490          0.649    0.00
```

Alternately, this could be expressed with dlyr like this where `FUN` is from above.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(g = rleid(clean_velocity)) %>%
  mutate(stopped = (clean_velocity == 0) * FUN(time)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-g)
```

### Note

```
DF <-
structure(list(time = c(2.51, 3.55, 4.56, 5.61, 6.65, 7.69, 8.74, 
9.78, 10.8, 11.9, 12.9, 14, 15, 16, 17.1), distance = c(0, 0, 
0.17, 0.68, 1.36, 1.87, 2.54, 2.88, 2.88, 2.88, 2.88, 2.88, 3.22, 
4.07, 4.75), slope = c(0, 0.168, 0.486, 0.654, 0.49, 0.638, 0.327, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.324, 0.817, 0.654, 0.81), rolling_velocity_avg = c(0.164, 
0.327, 0.45, 0.567, 0.527, 0.364, 0.241, 0.0817, 0, 0.081, 0.285, 
0.449, 0.651, 0.731, 0.649), clean_velocity = c(0, 0.327, 0.45, 
0.567, 0.527, 0.364, 0.241, 0, 0, 0, 0.285, 0.449, 0.651, 0.731, 
0.649)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

This one works well. I have one followup silly question. The output after I run your code it gives me the column labeled "stopped". This is exactly what I'm looking for. However, if I put the name of my tibble in to take a second look, the column vanishes. Is there a way to keep the column there? I thought the mutate() meant it should be attached to the end of the tibble.

Comment: Commands in the pipeline do not modify their inputs.  If you want to save the result you need to assign it to a variable.  `DF2 <- DF %>% ...`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(lead = lead(time)) %>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(`clean velocity`)) %>%
  mutate(StopDuration = (`clean velocity` == 0) * (row_number() == 1) * (max(lead) - time)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp, -lead)
```

Giving the following table:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 6
    time distance slope `rolling velocity avg` `clean velocity` StopDuration
   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>                  <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>
 1  2.51     0    0                     0.164             0             1.04
 2  3.55     0    0.168                 0.327             0.327         0   
 3  4.56     0.17 0.486                 0.45              0.45          0   
 4  5.61     0.68 0.654                 0.567             0.567         0   
 5  6.65     1.36 0.49                  0.527             0.527         0   
 6  7.69     1.87 0.638                 0.364             0.364         0   
 7  8.74     2.54 0.327                 0.241             0.241         0   
 8  9.78     2.88 0                     0.0817            0             3.12
 9 10.8      2.88 0                     0                 0             0   
10 11.9      2.88 0                     0.081             0             0   
11 12.9      2.88 0                     0.285             0.285         0   
12 14        2.88 0.324                 0.449             0.449         0   
13 15        3.22 0.817                 0.651             0.651         0   
14 16        4.07 0.654                 0.731             0.731         0   
15 17.1      4.75 0.81                  0.649             0.649        NA
```

Comment: I think so! Except when I pull the tibble back up, the stopduration column isn't there. This also happened with @denisafonin's answer

Comment: If you want to add the new table to the global environment you need to use `df -> df %>% rest of code`